# Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease'. during signed apk release. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detached

Tags: android, kotlin, apk

My android application is running fine but when I am creating android signed .apk file. following error occurs.
[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBpcp.png)

[this is gradle file (Project level)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi5ja.png),
[This is module level gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bje90.png). This error occurs every time I try to create signed apk. I am new to android, please if some one can help me.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler-31.0.2.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:31.0.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/31.0.2/kotlin-compiler-31.0.2.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

What should I do? I am also new to posting my query.

Comment: Solved this with lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }